# Why ZSH behaves differently in Tmux when I press CTRL or ALT before any other keys

Tags: terminal, zsh, tmux

ZSH normally works fine except when I use it in Tmux. When I press `ALT` or `CTRL` before any other keys like `Alt + Left Arrow` (to jump by words) or `Alt + Backspace` (to delete a word), it suddenly changes the prompt from this style:

[image]

to this style:

[image]

Then nothing works until I press the same key but with the `Right Arrow` key like `Alt + Right Arrow`.

It works fine when I do the same without Tmux, but I have no clue why it doesn't work in Tmux.

Answer (score 1):

`tmux` probably send other sequences for these key combinations to the shell as does your other terminal.

Check what you get after pressing `CTRL+V` (entering into a verbatim mode) and then the key combination in the different terminal emulators. With `xterm` I get e.g. `^[[1;3D]` for `ALT+LEFT ARROW`.

Then find where you define your keybindings (probably `~/.zshrc`) and change or better augment these for these new sequences.

Assuming you had before

```
bindkey "^[b" backward-word
```

just make it two lines, the second for the newly identified sequence:

```
bindkey "^[b"      backward-word
bindkey "^[[1;3D]" backward-word
```

Comment: Thank you. When I press `Ctrl-v` and any other keys, it shows me a code, but not for the `Alt-Backspace` key :'(. After pressing `Ctrl-v Alt-Backspace`, it change the arrow from `>` to `<` and nothing prints.

Comment: @mortymacs: I see, I did got a code on xterm and assumed it is working. Maybe you could first try to use `bindkey '\M-^H' ...` but this is probably the default. I'm no `tmux` expert, but I found https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57827 maybe this will give you some clue.

Comment: Thank a lot! `bindkey -e ${$(tput kDC3 2>/dev/null):-'\e[3;3~'} kill-word` fixed the issue which they mentioned in the answer.